# How to prevent removing node after dragging from "react-sortable-tree" to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I use "react-sortable-tree" for visualizing Folder Tree and "react-dnd" for copying node from Folder Tree to another component.

I want to use `shouldCopyOnOutsideDrop` prop to prevent deleting the draggable node from Folder Tree (SortableTree) to another component (DropTarget), but I receive undefined in callback and error after dropping node.

Please, help me fix the problem.

```
<SortableTree 
    shouldCopyOnOutsideDrop={node => { 
       console.log('!!shouldCopyOnOutsideDrop node', node); 
       // ... 
       return true;
    }} 
    dndType={'myDndType'} .... > ... 
</ SortableTree>

// !!shouldCopyOnOutsideDrop node {node: undefined, prevTreeIndex: undefined, prevPath: undefined}
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined return true;
```

Comment: are you returning something on onDrag or on onDrop?

Comment: No, I don't declarate this fuctions.

Comment: You will need to, on these events you will return an object which you will catch on drop

Comment: Please, give me an example of implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not using the `beginDrag` function. In the DragSource [documentation](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drag-source) see the function

```
beginDrag(props, monitor, component) {
    // Return the data describing the dragged item
    const item = { id: props.id };
    return item;
},
```

This function will tell the react-dnd about which object is actually dragged so when the drop event occurs react-dnd will give you the same object which you returned from this function. For example, in the DropTarget [documentation](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drop-target) see the function

```
  drop(props, monitor, component) {
    if (monitor.didDrop()) {
      // If you want, you can check whether some nested
      // target already handled drop
      return;
    }

    // Obtain the dragged item
    const item = monitor.getItem();

    // You can do something with it
    ChessActions.movePiece(item.fromPosition, props.position);

    // You can also do nothing and return a drop result,
    // which will be available as monitor.getDropResult()
    // in the drag source's endDrag() method
    return { moved: true };
  }
};
```

In this function monitor hold the item which was being dragged and dropped on drop target